# Store a file as a matrix of integers using multi-threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to use multi-threading to read a file formatted like this:

```
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

where each line is a string, e.g. the 1st one is:

```
"0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1"
```

and store it as a matrix like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

So far I have come up with:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def splitline(line):
    values = [int(char) for char in line.split()]
    return values

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    chunk = len(file.readlines()[0])
    file.seek(0)
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        matrix = pool.map(splitline, file, chunk)
```

but it is slower than simply using map():

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    matrix = []
    for line in file:
        matrix.append([value for value in map(int, line.split())])
```

Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong in my multithreading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how large your file is, it's pretty clear in your first snippet that `chunk = len(file.readlines()[0])` slurps the entire file into memory in a single-process. Then you fire up 4 processes (lots of overhead!) and split the string into chunks.

In your second snippet, you read the file line by line and you're done. This eliminates all of the multiprocessing overhead and cuts straight to the chase. For all the CPU power it takes to `file.readlines()`, you've completed all of the work and built the matrix by reading line by line while the first snippet is just getting around to starting up the processes.

Multiprocessing isn't helpful here, adding overhead and complexity with no benefit.